# Running mocha on travis with sequelize migration throws a "database does not exist" even creating one

Tags: node.js, postgresql, mocha.js, sequelize.js, travis-ci

I'm trying to run the mocha tests on my Node application and works locally perfectly well. After integrate this with travis, it keep saying that the database does not exist when I ran the migrate command even running the command to create the database as travis doc recommend.

So here is the build failing:
https://travis-ci.org/worknenjoy/gitpay/builds/242391063

Here the travis config:
https://github.com/worknenjoy/gitpay/blob/login/.travis.yml

The package.json:
https://github.com/worknenjoy/gitpay/blob/login/package.json

The migrate command:
https://github.com/worknenjoy/gitpay/blob/login/migrate.js

So in the travis.yml I have:
    
    `before_script:
      - psql -c 'create database gitPay;' -U postgres`

Why travis cannot find the database when the migration execute?

Comment: With what user are you connecting to the database, and what permissions does the user have on the newly created database?

Comment: The migration import this config to connect in the database:

"test": {
        "username": "postgres",
        "password": "postgres",
        "database": "gitPay",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 5432,
        "dialect": "postgres",
        "logging": false
    }